# How to "Decorate" a control in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want that some of the controls in my window will be surrounded by a border and a label above them that will contains a title, which tells something about a control (e.g. a list of persons, surrounded by a border, and above the list there is a label with the text "My Persons"). Since I want apply this on many controls, I don't want to write a specific xaml for each one of them. Should I create a user control, or is there a way to use styles/templates for that?

Visual Example:

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/829214/example.GIF

Answer (score 0):

I would look into adorners and the adorner layer.

Comment: It looks like with this solution I should write a class that derives from Adorner, and implement the logic there. Why is it better than a user control? 
Isn't there another way to do it using xaml only?

Comment: you could create a user control, and you could do this xaml only--probably take a LOT more code though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this would be to create a custom/user control that derives from contentcontrol.  Use a contentcontrol to vary the content and design the control to look however you want.